# MediaPlayer control

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF Caliburn.Micro application, and I want to use `System.Window.Media.MediaPlayer` to play audio. I know how to start playing, but how can I know when the playing is done, so I can for example disable Pause button etc?

**My code:**

```
var audio = Tpv.GetAudio(tpv.TpvId);
var file = Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", ".wma");
File.WriteAllBytes(file, audio);

var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute));
player.Play();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the MediaEnded event on the MediaPlayer.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaended

If you want more control over the playback, like pausing, and seeking then use a MediaTimeline and a Storyboard.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediatimeline.source.aspx
- [WPF: Implementing a MediaPlayer Audio / Video Seeker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869761/wpf-implementing-a-mediaplayer-audio-video-seeker)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately, these solutions are not for Caliburn.Micro when I don't have code-behind...